# Deep-copying with ProtoBuf in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, protocol-buffers, protobuf-c

Say I had an array of pointers, each of which points to structs which may once again have pointers to other structs in them; is it possible to handle serializing this using protobuf? If so, how?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean with "How" do you want an explanation, how to use protobuf in c++?

Comment: @AlanStokes: I'm actually working with both for different projects. Help with either would be great.

Comment: @MikeMB: I was hoping for an example where nested pointers might come into play. The examples I was able to find were all fairly trivial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way you're thinking about this problem is the reverse of how you need to think if you're considering protobufs. Protobufs don't take an existing data structure and serialize them. They take a serialization protocol and create data structures for you that you populate.

With that said, nested serialization is pretty simple:

```
// nested.proto
message Inner {
    required string value = 1;
}

message Outer {
    required Inner inner = 1;
}

message Pointers {
    repeated Outer outer = 1;
}
```

Assuming you've correctly compiled this, you can use this protocol working from the outside in. That is, you start with the highest structure, `Pointers`, and work your way into the `Inner` object:

```
Pointers pointers;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    auto outer = pointers.add_outer();
    auto inner = outer->mutable_inner();
    inner->set_value(std::to_string(i));
}

std::stringstream stream;
pointers.SerializeToOstream(&stream);

...

Pointers parsed_pointers;
parsed_pointers.ParseFromIstream(&stream);
for (int i = 0; i < parsed_pointers.outer_size(); ++i) {
    std::cout << parsed_pointers.outer(i).inner().value() << std::endl;
}

// This prints 0, 1, 2, ..., 9 all on their own lines
```

It's possible to start with the `Inner` message, but the way you pass ownership to an `Outer` message is not as simple or obvious:

```
Inner* inner = new Inner();
inner->set_value("Hello world");
Outer outer;
outer.set_allocated_inner(inner);
```

Calling that method will capture ownership of the `inner` pointer so that you shouldn't manually `delete` it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

There is another method I think also helpful. Since `.set_allocated_*(A)` has a side effect which will destroy `A`. To just copy from `A`, you can try `.mutable_*()->CopyFrom(A)`.